# App Store Connect responses with code -22020 (Unable to validate your application. We are unable to create an authentication session.)

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, codemagic

I'm trying to publish the iOS app to the App Store with Codemagic and it is throwing me this error:

```
Publishing artifact Runner.ipa
Publishing artifact my-app_1_artifacts.zip
Publishing Runner.ipa to App Store Connect
> /usr/bin/xcrun altool --validate-app -f /Users/builder/clone/build/ios/ipa/Runner.ipa -t 
ios -u myemail@email.com -p @env:APP_STORE_CONNECT_PASSWORD --output-format normal
2020-04-03 23:48:44.936 altool[10392:67814] *** Error: Unable to validate archive 
'/Users/builder/clone/build/ios/ipa/Runner.ipa'.
2020-04-03 23:48:44.936 altool[10392:67814] *** Error: code -22020 (Unable to validate your 
application. We are unable to create an authentication session.)

Failed to publish to App Store Connect
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a problem with the credentials and issuer id